# Quiet failure of attempting to decline a flag without having accepted the moderator agreement

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools, declined-flags

As a moderator on [Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/), I tried to decline a flag on meta. When I clicked on the “declined…” button that is supposed to bring up decline reasons, nothing happened other than the animated `...` signaling that the client was waiting for an answer from the server.

The console told me that [https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/issues/408;419;418;417;416;415;414;413;411;412;410;409?*=1464207890898*](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/issues/408;419;418;417;416;415;414;413;411;412;410;409?_=1464207890898) and [https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/admin/dismiss-flag?=1464207895008](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/admin/dismiss-flag?_=1464207895008) were returning a 400 Bad Request status.

Trying to dismiss the flag as helpful revealed the problem:

```
{"ErrorMessage":"You must accept the Moderator Agreement; click the mod link"}
```

Ah, I see. This was the first flag on Emacs meta since the election, and I hadn't accepted the agreement on meta, only on main.

Please show a meaningful error message when declining.

Comment: Won't happen very often, but is confusing when it does. Agree

Comment: Seems like it would make more sense to have the single mod agreement apply to both parts of the site rather than needing to accept it twice.

Comment: You should post that as a [feature-request] @Catija

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're right, this is confusing. It will be less quiet after the next build.