# Unify Main and Meta Mod agreements so that newly appointed moderators only have to accept the agreement once

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderators

A recent question pointed out that, apparently, the moderator agreement must be signed once for a Main site and a second time for that site's child meta site.

[Quiet failure of attempting to decline a flag without having accepted the moderator agreement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279663/quiet-failure-of-attempting-to-decline-a-flag-without-having-accepted-the-modera)

Is this necessary? Is there something about how the system is designed that requires two separate acceptances of the agreement?

My [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279663/quiet-failure-of-attempting-to-decline-a-flag-without-having-accepted-the-modera#comment906557_279663) on that question has many upvotes, so I decided to turn the comment into a feature request.

As this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272209/284336) explains, the mods are the same on both parts of the site. If that weren't the case, I would completely understand this separation.

So, can the powers-that-be make it possible for newly elected/appointed moderators to only accept the agreement once for the entire site?

---

*<sup>Note, I still believe that if a mod is elected/appointed on a **second** site, they should have to re-accept. This only relates to single site main-meta crossovers.</sup>

Comment: Hmmm - I don't recall accepting the mod agreement on any meta site but have had to on each site I'm a mod. And I definitely have mod functionality on all the relevant meta sites...

Comment: If that's the case, I'd be interested to hear an explanation for why the mod in the linked question was required to do so.

Comment: I had to accept the agreement separately on [sf] and its meta.

Comment: I also had to accept it separately on SFF main and meta. +1 to this feature request.

Comment: And I can now confirm that I did just have to accept it twice myself. :D

Comment: @Catija Congrats on becoming mod on Arts & Crafts and Arts & Crafts Meta.

Comment: @wythagoras Good point! I accepted the agreement twice, which means I'm actually two mods at once... then again, everyone did that... so it all averages out the same. :(

Comment: Was this implemented after [this fix](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279689/377214) rolled out?

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog no the two are unrelated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has shipped.

It was supposed to ship with the mod agreement v2 but there was a lot of churn with the requirements and it slipped through the cracks. (100% my bad.)

Now accepting on a site will mark you as an active moderator for both the main and meta sites.  If you have already accepted agreement v2 on just one of those sites, you will no longer need to go back and accept on the other to maintain your access.

**Technical note:** This is done using your account history. Any time you make an agreement decision on a site, that decision is also recorded at the account level.  When verifying your agreement status, we now simply check the account history rather than the site history to see if you've accepted on either the main or meta.